# Proof of Root Test?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I have been trying my own proof of the root test since I don't quite understand [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694354/how-to-prove-the-root-test-for-series).

So I will show what I have and explain why I'm stuck.

---

Suppose $a_n \geq 0$ and $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = r$.

Claim: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if $r < 1$.

Proof: We know that $r \geq 0$ since $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \geq 0$, so suppose $0 \leq r < 1$.

Then $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to 0}} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = r$ implies the following given any $\epsilon > 0$.
        \begin{align*}
   \exists N > 0 \text{ such that } n > N &\implies |\sqrt[n]{a_n} - r| < \epsilon\\
               &\implies |\sqrt[n]{a_n}| - |r| < \epsilon \,\, \text{ by the reverse triangle ineq.}\\
               &\implies \sqrt[n]{a_n} - r < \epsilon \,\,\text{ since } r,\, a_n \geq 0\\
               &\implies r - \sqrt[n]{a_n} > -\epsilon\\
               &\implies 1 - \sqrt[n]{a_n} > -\epsilon \,\,\text{ since } r < 1\\
               &\implies a_n < (1 + \epsilon)^n\\
               &\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1 + \epsilon)^n
   \end{align*}
        But $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to \infty}} \frac{(1-\epsilon)^{n+1}}{(1 - \epsilon)^n} = 1 + \epsilon > 1$ since $\epsilon > 0$.

So by the ratio test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1 + \epsilon)^n$ diverges and by the comparison test, we can't say anything about
        $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

---

So clearly I've hit a snag going down this route. I've been trying to think of alternate routes but I can't think of any. Are there any hints that can be offered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose $\epsilon$ to be small enough so that $r+\epsilon < 1$.
Then there exists $N$ such that $|\sqrt[n]{a_n} -r | < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. This implies $\sqrt[n]{a_n} < r+\epsilon < 1$ for all $n \ge N$ so $\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n \le \sum_{n=N}^\infty (r+\epsilon)^n < \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! But are we allowed to just choose $\epsilon$ to be within a certain range? What happens when $r + \epsilon \geq 1$?

Comment: @TristanBatchler Different choices of $\epsilon$ will give different upper bounds on $\sum a_n$. If you choose $\epsilon$ too big, you will get a divergent series like you did in your attempt. All you need is an upper bound that is a convergent series, and you can choose whichever $\epsilon$ you like (thanks to the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = r$) in order to achieve that.