# Show that a series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I am studying about series and confused when doing this question.

Let $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $a_i\ge0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sup\ (a_n)^\frac1n=L\lt1$, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

The question has a hint which is using comparison test.

I don't understand why L doesn't equal 1 since for any b$\gt$0, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\ (b)^\frac1n=1$ and I have zero idea about how to form a new series to use comparsion test.

Comment: Search for “root test proof”, e.g. here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694354/42969 .

Comment: Thank you! I don't even know it call root test.

Comment: As a general hint: There aren't that many series for which convergence can be shown "directly", i.e. without a comparison to other series. The geometric series is the main one where this is possible, and very often, a comparison to a geometric series is the way to go.